# How to detect a possible deadlock in a hudson build?

Tags: hudson

I am calling a perl script using my hudson job.
This script is responsible for getting data from cvs and svn and then running 
an operation on this data.
Now during the weekend this script just didn't stop running.
This happened because a particular cvs location was locked and the script was waiting for the locks to be released.
How can I make hudson notify me in such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [build timeout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin).

Comment: This plugin works on the assumption that that my build always takes the same amount of time.But this build doesn't take a constant time always.Is there a plugin that can parse the hudson logs in real time?

Comment: Not that I am aware off. You can either go for a huge timeout (e.g. 24 hours) or create a script that runs the checkout as a background process and kills the checkout under certain conditions.